# Check if a form has a key?

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

In asp.net i need to check if a form has certain keys in it. How do i do this? i thought form.HasKey() would work but then i found out there is no overload and really just tells you if its empty or not. How do i check for a key without causing an exception? The key is allowed to be empty.

Comment: Key?  What key?  Not aware of a "HasKey" method either.  Do you mean request parameters?   i.e.  Request.Params?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(v)
```

Comment: Just make sure that you are `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 4):

If you use it alot, try this..

```
public static bool ContainsKey(this HttpRequestBase request, string key)
{
    return request.Params.AllKeys.Contains(key);
}

if(Request.ContainsKey("keyToSearch"))
   DoSomething();
```